# SQL - Using Count with WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a simple, at first sight, SQL query, but I can't wrap my head around what I'm doing wrong.

**Problem**

Imagine these are my tables:

*TableUsers*

```
UserID      FirstName   LastName
1           Bill        Johnson
2           Alex        Agnew
3           Mike        Owen
4           Kate        Ryan
```

*TableArticles*

```
ArticleID   Description
1           Bananas
2           Eggs
3           Milk
```

*TableOrders*

```
OrderID     UserID      ArticleID
1           1           1
2           1           2
3           2           3
4           2           2
5           3           3
```

I want to list all users who have at least one order linked to their name, count how many orders and count how many of a specific article they ordered:

**Desired result**

```
UserID  FirstName   # Orders    # Banana orders     # Egg orders
1       Bill            2           1               1
2       Alex            2           0               1
3       Mike            1           0               0
```

**I have tried:**

```
SELECT
    UserID,
    FirstName,
    COUNT(*) AS '# Orders',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableOrders O WHERE O.UserID = TableOrders.UserID AND O.ArticleID = 1) AS '# Banana orders',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableOrders O WHERE O.UserID = TableOrders.UserID AND O.ArticleID = 2) AS '# Egg orders',
FROM TableUsers
LEFT JOIN TableOrders ON TableOrders.UserID = TableUsers.UserID
GROUP BY UserID, FirstName
HAVING Count(*) > 0;
```

But I'm getting an error saying the ArticleID needs to be in an aggregate function or group by clause. If I add the ArticleID to the group by clause, users with multiple orders are shown more than once...

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: `HAVING Count(*) > 0` doesn't reject any rows at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT o.UserID, o.FirstName, COUNT(*) AS num_orders,
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.ArticleID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_bananas, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN o.ArticleID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_eggs 
FROM TableUsers u JOIN
     TableOrders o
     ON o.UserID = u.UserID
GROUP BY UserID, FirstName;
```

Notes:

- You want users with orders, so just use an inner join, not an outer join.
- The `HAVING` clause is then not necessary.
- Table aliases make the query easier to read and write.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  It is better to name the columns so they don't need to be escaped.